# docker export import for windows containers

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Actual there is no support for export option for windows containers.

Is there another way to transport an image to another host host?

I am not using the docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a registry other than Docker Hub. There are multiple hosted and self hosted options since the API is documented. This includes the minimal [docker registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) and the [harbor](https://goharbor.io/) project that is part of the CNCF.